# Azure Information Protection Scanner deployment - error acquiring token

Tags: azure

I am trying to deploy Azure Information Protection Scanner on a Windows Server 2016 VM following the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/deploy-aip-scanner).

I have completed the Pre-Requisites and Install the scanner sections and the Azure Information Protection Scanner service is running with an AD account that is synced to Azure AD and does have logon locally rights as a local administrator on the VM.
I am now trying to complete the Get an Azure AD token for the scanner section.
I have created the 2 Azure applications that the above guide describes, noted the details and then tried to run the following PowerShell command to acquire an Azure AD token:

**Set-AIPAuthentication -webAppId "The ID of my Web app / API app" -webAppKey" The Key value generated by my Web app / API app" -nativeAppId "The ID of my Native app"**

When prompted I then enter Azure AD credentials for the service account. These are accepted and I see the following:
[Microsoft sign in popup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avMFJ.png)

I click on accept and then see the following PowerShell error:

[Set-AIPAuthentication error acquiring token screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpkaC.png)

Can you advise are there further steps that are required to acquire the Azure AD token for the AIP scanner/

I have included the contents of the MSIPPowershell.iplog below.
Thanks,
Gareth

---

### MSIPPowershell.iplog

Error   2018-11-14 15:14:31.4437    MSIP.ServiceClient  powershell (4996)   Failed to bootstrap to azure rights management service server https://b69c1d0c-2d7f-47d9-a438-410f53dcdd38.rms.eu.aadrm.com/_wmcs/licensing "System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations
System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+MoveNextRunner.Run
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
Microsoft.InformationProtection.ServiceClient.Bootstrapping.Bootstrapper+d__66.MoveNext" "Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.InformationProtectionException: The request is not supported. HRESULT: 0x80070032
   at Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.SafeNativeMethods.ThrowOnErrorCode(Int32 hrError)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.SafeNativeMethods.IpcGetTemplateList(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean suppressUI, Boolean offline, Boolean hasUserConsent, IntPtr parentWindow, CultureInfo cultureInfo, GetTemplateListFlags flags, Object credentialType, WaitHandle cancelCurrentOperation)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.RMS.MSIPC.Msipc.GetTemplateList(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean forceDownload, Boolean suppressUI, Boolean offline, IntPtr parentWindow, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Object credentialType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.RMS.MSIPC.RightsPolicyTemplate.GetAll(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean forceDownload, Boolean suppressUI, Boolean offline, IntPtr parentWindow, Object credentialType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.ServiceClient.Bootstrapping.Bootstrapper.ListTemplates(ConnectionPoint connectionPoint, Boolean silent, Boolean forceDownloadTemplates, String oauth2AccessToken, IntPtr parentWindow, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.ServiceClient.Bootstrapping.Bootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass68_0.b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
...and:
Error   2018-11-14 15:14:31.4594    AIP powershell (4996)   Error acquiring token   "System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run
System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run
System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline
System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate
System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute
System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord
Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.SetAIPAuthenticationCmdLet.ProcessRecord
Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.AIPBaseCmdlet.HandleTerminatingException"    "Microsoft.InformationProtectionAndControl.InformationProtectionException: The request is not supported. HRESULT: 0x80070032
   at Microsoft.InformationProtection.Powershell.AIP.Commandlets.SetAIPAuthenticationCmdLet.ProcessRecord()"    DS\svc-aip-scanner  10

Answer (score 0):

We have now discovered that as our Azure subscription was acquired before February 2018 we had to activate Azure Rights Management to get this to work. As soon as this was activated the Set-AIPAuthentication cmdlet completed successfully.